# How to properly use setState() in my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the correct way to update `this.state.processDuration` in order to avoid a warning message?:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state

```
  fetchData = () => {
      this.setState(
        this.state.processDuration = (new Date(this.state.endTime)-new Date(this.state.endDate)) / 60000
      )
  }
```

Comment: this.setState({
      processDuration : (new Date(this.state.endTime)-new Date(this.state.endDate)) / 60000
  }    )

Comment: @Nemer: If I write `console.log(this.state.processDuration)` right after `this.setState({...}”`, then the value of `this.state.processDuration` is not updated. Why does it happen? If I do `this.state.processDuration = (new Date...)`, then everything works fine (except the Warning message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` receives as argument an Object with the key/values you want to update.

You can look through the [setState() docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more examples.

Use it like this:

```
   fetchData = () => {
          this.setState({
            processDuration: (new Date(this.state.endTime)-new Date(this.state.endDate)) / 60000
          })
      }
```

Because setting state is `asynchronous` and you use current state, it is recommended that you use the updater function instead of passing an Object.

```
   fetchData = () => {
          this.setState((state) => ({
               processDuration: (new Date(state.endTime)-new Date(state.endDate)) / 60000   
          }));
      }
```

If you want to do something **after** state was changed, you can pass an optional callback that will be called after state was updated and component re-rendered:

```
      this.setState(
         // Updater function, has current state/props as parameters
         (state, props) => ({
              processDuration: (new Date(state.endTime)-new Date(state.endDate)) / 60000   
         }), 
         // V -- This will be called after state was updated
         () => { console.log('State was updated!', this.state); }
      )
```

Comment: If I write `console.log(this.state.processDuration)` right after `this.setState({...}”`, then the value of `this.state.processDuration` is not updated. Why does it happen? If I do `this.state.processDuration = (new Date...)`, then everything works fine (except the Warning message).

Comment: @ScalaBoy Setting state is `asynchronous`, so the change does not happen instantly, but can happen at any time in the future (usually happens quickly, within the next few milliseconds). So `setState` just tells React, "hey, change state.x to 5", and React will change it as soon as possible, but not instantly in order to improve app performance. If you want to log something only after the state was changed, `setState` also receive another callback parameter that is called **after** state was changed.

Comment: I tested the second approach. The issue is the same. It takes some time to update the value of `processDuration`, but I need it to be done instantaneously (it should be as quickly as `this.state.processDuration = (new Date ...)`).

Comment: So, how can I execute `console.log` (and other code inside fetchData) after the update was done?

Comment: Thanks, @Cristy! Could you please upvote my question, because I do not consider that it is so primitive to be downvoted.

Comment: I did, but the question will probably be downvoted more, as all the answers can be easily found by reading the docs of the `setState` function.